# NoneType object has no attribute node

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am creating a discord music bot and I have divided it into two parts one is bot.py (just containing simple code to run bot) and second is music.py (containing lavalink and other stuff).

when I am typing @join in my it says join cmd successful but the bot is not joining vc and when I am typing @play  it's showing NoneType Object (player) has no attribute node.

Waiting eagerly for someone to help

bot.py file:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'CONFIDENTIALTOKEN'
PREFIX = '@'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= PREFIX)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} is online')
    bot.load_extension('cogs.music')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

music.py file:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import lavalink
from discord import utils
from discord import Embed

class MusicCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.bot.music = lavalink.Client(self.bot.user.id)
        self.bot.music.add_node=('localhost', 7000, 'WzALFn2025', 'na', 'music-node')
        self.bot.add_listener(self.bot.music.voice_update_handler, 'on_socket_response')
        self.bot.music.add_event_hook(self.track_hook)

    @commands.command(name= 'join')
    async def join(self, ctx):
        print('join command worked')
        member = utils.find(lambda m: m.id == ctx.author.id, ctx.guild.members)
        if member is not None and member.voice is not None:
            vc = member.voice.channel
            player = self.bot.music.player_manager.create(ctx.guild.id, endpoint=str(ctx.guild.region))
            if not player.is_connected:
                player.store('channel', ctx.channel.id)
                await self.connect_to(ctx.guild.id, str(vc.id))

    @commands.command(name = 'play')
    async def play(self, ctx, *, query):
        try:
            player = self.bot.music.player_manager.get(ctx.guild.id) 
            query = f'ytsearch:{query}'
            results = await player.node.get_tracks(query)
            tracks = results['tracks'][0:10]
            i = 0
            query_results = ''
            for track in tracks:
                i = i + 1
                query_results = query_results + f'({i}) {track["info"]["title"]} - {track ["info"]["uri"]}\n'
            embed = Embed()
            embed.description = query_results
            await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
        
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)

    async def track_hook(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, lavalink.events.QueueEndEvent):
            guild_id = int(event.player.guild_id)
            await self.connect_to(guild_id, None)

    async def connect_to(self, guild_id: int, channel_id: str):
        ws = self.bot._connection._get_websocket(guild_id)
        await ws.voice_state(str(guild_id), channel_id)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(MusicCog(bot))
```

Comment: Any solution? please

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write your join function as:

```py
@client.command(name='join', help='This command makes the bot join the voice channel')
async def join(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        return await ctx.send("You're not in a voice channel.")
    
    else:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
```

you can check that https://github.com/GabrielDornelles/SEULGI-SR/blob/main/run.py for other funcionalities or simple stuff for music bot